# Package bound resource use for multiple go packages

Tags: go, resources, package

For a contrived example:

I have 2 packages, repo.com/alpha/A & repo.net/beta/B. package A uses package B, both structured as example.

```
A:
    main.go

B: 
    b.go
    templates \
        1.tmpl
        2.tmpl
```

In main.go of package A, I'd need to access the templates directory of package B.

b.go

```
var templates string

templates = templatepath

func init(){
    templatepath, _ = filepath.Abs("./templates")
}
```

main.go

```
import(
    repo.net/beta/B
)

func main(){
   fmt.Printf("%s", B.templates)
}
```

So the problem being in my more complex use case & the contrived example here is that B.templates will be in the directory for package A, where I need to establish and reference the directory of the imported path.  This is part of learning and navigating the Go way of doing things, and my understanding is probably basic, so I need to understand how to do this in a Go context.

My use case is a package that uses other packages that do things for the base package, and these external packages may use standard web resources files(css, html, js) the problem being I'm having immediate trouble packaging and referencing them abstractly enough for what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you have to either use something like go-bindata or so, or simply embed the templates in your `B` package as consts.

**tmpl1.go**:

```
const tmpl1 = `........`
```

Comment: I was just reading on go-bindata. What I want seems difficult to conceptualize in go terms right now, and hearing 'can't' is a red flag of sorts. I'm certain the modularity I'm trying can be achieved, but at what effort?

Comment: the problem is `filepath.Abs("./templates")` is relative to the executable's current working path, and this applies to any language really.

Comment: If the answer is 'You can't', then question becomes 'how is modularity and resource sharing achieved idiomatically in Go especially dynamically where resource location may vary, how have others solved the issue?'.

Comment: Others have solved this issue by using go-bindata or similar packages or simply embedding templates directly in the go code.